# Serving ReactJs bundle from an express static server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I've created a ReactJS and build its bundle using webpack. Now I wish to serve it from an embedded machine with not too many resources available.

So I've decided to build a express static server. My project has another server that runs API's on port 3001. Here is my code for the static server:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const port = process.env.PORT || 80;
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");
const morgan = require("morgan");

const app = express();

// logger (see morgan codes)
app.use(
    morgan(
        ':date[clf] (:response-time ms) :remote-addr - :remote-user ":method :url HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length] bytes'
    )
);


// this assumes that all your app files
// `public` directory relative to where your server.js is
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static"));

// API calls are redirected to the API Server on port 3001
app.use(
    ["/status", "/login", "/reboot", "/reset", "/changepassword", "/graphql"],
    proxy({ target: "http://localhost:3001", changeOrigin: true })
);


app.get("*", function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "index.html"));
});


app.listen(port);
console.log("Page server started on port " + port);
```

Running it I'm got the following on log:

```
[HPM] Proxy created: /  ->  http://localhost:3001
Page server started on port 8080
21/Jun/2018:00:23:01 +0000 (5.251 ms) ::1 - - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 - bytes
21/Jun/2018:00:23:01 +0000 (1.085 ms) ::1 - - "GET /static/css/main.3fc8ac40.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - bytes
21/Jun/2018:00:23:01 +0000 (1.168 ms) ::1 - - "GET /static/js/main.b300fb14.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - bytes
21/Jun/2018:00:23:01 +0000 (0.324 ms) ::1 - - "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 - bytes
21/Jun/2018:00:23:21 +0000 (0.408 ms) ::1 - - "GET /static/css/main.3fc8ac40.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - bytes
```

So, my bundle is being served, but my ReactJS application does not show up in screen (I'm getting an empty string).

What is missing on my server to allow me to navigate through the screens?